# Android get GPS Location in the background

Tags: android, gps

Is there a way to track gps location even if the app is running in the background?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, create a `Service` and request location updates there.
This should point you to the right direction: http://niravranpara.blogspot.se/2013/04/android-get-current-gps-location.html

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // here you get location updates
    // the link I gave you doesn't tell u that, but it is obvious?
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping, how do i create a service i've not used gps before?

Comment: dont forge to add your service to the Manifest file

Comment: also mate, i just noticed the link. the way to start a service is with the method startService, read the docs. DO NOT use a Constructor like they did!